# Заполнение формы данными

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

С бэкэнда приходит json. Как можно раскидать данные в форму?

```
function funcSuccess(data) {
        console.log(data);

}
```

Object {date: "23.03.2016", description: "abc",  title: "123", status: "1"}

```
<form name="editForm" method="POST" >  

<input id="editTitle" type="text" class="form-control"></input>

<textarea id="editDescription"  class="noresize form-control animated "></textarea>

<input id="editDate"  type='text' class="form-control" value="" readonly>

<select id='edittStatus' class="selectpicker form-control">
     <option value="0">CREATE</option>
      <option value="1">CLOSED</option>             
</select> 

</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //Тестовый код
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //Ваши данные - объект. Тут я его сам создаю.
      var data = {
        date: "23.03.2016",
        description: "abc",
        title: "123",
        status: "1"
      };

      //С помощью jquery меняем текстовое содержимое блока с id=editDescription
      //В качестве аргумента передаем нужное поле обьекта data.
      //Поскольку ассоциативный массив = объект то можно обратится просто через точку
      $("#editDescription").text(data.description);
      $("select#edittStatus").val(data.status);
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="editDescription">
    Тут результат
  </div>
  <form>
  <select id='edittStatus' class="selectpicker form-control">
     <option value="0">CREATE</option>
      <option value="1">CLOSED</option>
    </select>
  </form> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: c textarea работает нормально, а вот в input нужно как то вставить в аттрибут value="" . И тот же select не знаю как сделать чтоб был выбран уже тот который нужен в форме

Comment: решил  $("#editTitle").val(data.title); используя val. Вопрос как выбрать нужное значение в select`e актуальный

Comment: обновил код - добавил select там вместо .text используйте val()

Comment: почитайте краткий учебник по jquery [тут](http://www.wisdomweb.ru/JQd/dom.php). Там за час все проштудировать можно с учетом выполнения заданий. Оно того стоит.

Comment: Всё работает. Сейчас правда уперся что selectpicker мешает выбору значения в select. Если его уберу то всё работает, разберусь. Вообщем спасибо.